# Is this the "proper" way to update an attribute in Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Thanks for looking. I am learning rails and am building a web app. I am trying to be "RESTful" and thinking in those terms. Therefore, I am looking at my data as a resource. Suppose I have a table called microposts and a column "votes" in which it counts how many people upvoted or downvoted. I have it working this way:

In the view:

```
<td>
    <%= form_for feed_item do |f| %>
        <div><%= hidden_field_tag 'todo', 'upvote' %></div>
        <div class="action"><%= f.submit "Up" %></div>
    <% end %>
</td>
<td>
    <%= form_for feed_item do |f| %>
      <div><%= hidden_field_tag 'todo', 'downvote' %></div>
      <div class="action"><%= f.submit "Down" %></div>
    <% end %>
<td>
```

When, a user clicks on the button, it calls the "update" method in the controller. Then, in the controller, I have this in update:

```
  def update
    @todo = params[:todo]
    if @todo == "upvote"
      Micropost.find(params[:id]).increment!(:votes)
      flash[:success] = "Increase micropost vote"
      redirect_to root_path
    elsif @todo == "downvote"
      Micropost.find(params[:id]).decrement!(:votes)
      flash[:success] = "Decrease micropost vote"
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end
```

I pass a hidden field to know if the button pressed is an "upvote" or a "downvote". So, if I want to change any other micropost attribute, I need to have more and more if statements. I don't think I am doing this right. What is the rails way to update attributes or a record in the DB?

Thanks much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A more RESTful reworking is to define each of your actions as a separate route, GET if you must, POST ideally, to receive each of these types of calls:

```
before_filter :load_micropost

def load_micropost
  @micropost = Micropost.find(params[:id])
end

def upvote
  @micropost.increment!(:votes)
  flash[:success] = "Increase micropost vote"
  redirect_to root_path
end

def downvote
  @micropost.decrement!(:votes)
  flash[:success] = "Decrease micropost vote"
  redirect_to root_path
end
```

Don't forget to create methods like `load_micropost` to handle routine loading of models. There's no point in having several different calls strewn about your method that, at some point in the future, might require adjusting.

You'd route these like this:

```
map.resources :microposts,
  :member => {
    :upvote => :post,
    :downvote => :post
  }
```

Another thing you might want to consider is adding a table that records who voted for what so you can audit and adjust if required. This makes it easy to unwind any fraudulent activity without having to reset the votes wholesale.

You can also make simple links that POST if you ask for them:

```
<%= link_to('Upvote', upvote_micropost_path(feed_item), :method => :post) %>
```

This will take care of rendering whatever form elements are required.

Comment: `GET` with destructive action? Don't even think about it! REST reserves `PUT` for updating, which is IMO better than `POST` in this case.

Comment: `PUT` is for updates, `POST` creates new records, generally speaking. Generally votes are created once, rarely adjusted, which is why `POST` might be appropriate here. You're right that `GET` is trouble because of link preloaders and so forth. That's why I said "if you must".

Comment: Thanks tadman! I am on Rails 3 so I use :put and your solution works

Answer (score 4):

I would create additional actions `upvote`/`downvote` (or just `vote`) and add them as a `member` resources. REST is not really limited to CRUD, you can always add other actions. E.g in Rails 2 it would be:

`map.resources :my_resource, :member => {:upvote => :put}`

and then you can use `upvote_my_resource_path` and add `upvote` action to your controller so you don't mess up with `update`.

Comment: While a valid way to do it, it is not purely RESTful, which the question asked.  Not that I think REST is always the answer.

Comment: In my case, I use Rails 3.0, does it look like this? resources :microposts do member do put :upvote, :downvote end end? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would save votes in separate model `Vote` `(micropost_id, user_id, positive, created_at)`, also add field to microposts `votes` or something like that, which will contain `(count_up_votes - count_down_votes)`.

After that I'll create new resource `votes` under microposts, so you will have route like `micropost_votes_path`.

If you choose that design, your users will be able cancel their votes and you will be able prevent multiple votes per user.

Answer (score 0):

First, add a virtual attribute to your model:

```
Class Micropost
  def change_vote(value)
    if value == 'upvote'
      votes += 1
    elseif value == 'downvote'
      votes -= 1
    end
  end
end
```

then in your form, be sure to have it use the form helpers: (assuming feed_item is a micropost)

```
<%= form_for feed_item do |f| %>
    <div><%= f.hidden_field 'change_vote', 'upvote' %></div>
    <div class="action"><%= f.submit "Up" %></div>
<% end %>
```

This delivers the resource back in the proper form for REST. All the controller needs to do is:

```
def update
  @mp = Micropost.find(params[:id])
  @mp.update_attributes(params[:micropost])
  if params[:micropost][:change_vote] == 'upvote' 
    flash[:success] = "Increase micropost vote"
  else
    flash[:success] = "Decrease micropost vote"
  end
  redirect_to root_url
end
```

Of course, this doesn't take into consideration validations and such yet, but that's the RESTful way to do it

Comment: I guess this is exactly same thing that was in original question, at least from the RESTful point of view. Truly RESTful way would probably be to create spinner with vote count, display it with `edit` action and send it back as update request along with other attributes. Another question is who needs such a thing.

Comment: It's not quite the same, in the sense that the original post was not restful because it did not pass actual resource in the request.  OTher than that, it is of course refactored to put logic in the model, as it should be.  My way, the update call can be used whether to update other attributes or the vote;  it's all a resource that is being updated.

Comment: There's so much needless duplication in here that it confuses what's actually being done. Using `attr_accessor` as a way to trigger behaviors on save is lazy and dangerous.

Comment: It's not attr_accessor, it's a virtual attribute.  Same technique as encrypting a password.  See http://railscasts.com/episodes/16-virtual-attributes  As for duplication, what duplication? This solution cuts down on the code, I don't see any duplication. (The flash message is a tad odd, but there just to keep the same functionality).  Furthermore, this code can coexist with regular updating of the Micropost object.... further reducing duplication.  Setting up new routes, methods, findds... *that's* needless duplication.

Comment: I guess I have to clarify that I don't need it to be "truly" restful but I want it to be the "rails way" of doing things.